# Nat skin with tinymce as the editor

Tags: themes, twiki

How can I have tinyMCE editor with the Nat skin in twiki. I mean when I say skin = nat in the twiki preferences my editor automatically changes to nateditor. though i want tinyMCE as the editor. How can I have nat as the skin but tinyMCE as the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading from twiki to [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org). This has long been solved on NatSkin and NatEditPlugin.

Comment: can't i do the same in TWiki. I mean there is no obvious path of migration to foswiki. It needs a lot of shifting... of content, structure and themeing.

Comment: Unfortunately this code isn't maintained on TWiki and has advanded a lot on Foswiki the recent 1.5 years since the fork. Please have a look at http://foswiki.org/System/UpgradeGuide to get some sense on how much effort it is. There's also a TWikiCompatibilityPlugin to mitigate the process. All TWiki plugins have been ported to Foswiki. See http://foswiki.org/Development/StatusOfPortingExtensionsToFoswiki. Lots of new plugins have been created for Foswiki only. Motorola, Yahoo and many more already upgraded their major wiki installations to Foswiki. So you won't regret it :)

Answer (score 0):

shifting from twiki to foswiki doesn't require allot of shifting - its pretty much the same amount of work as migrating from twiki 4.2 to twiki 5.0 - but with more bug fixes (in foswiki) :)

Comment: i tried doing that and was stuck at LDAP plugin. I am not able to configure it for the foswiki.. Even for the twiki.. it was compatible with older versions of twiki.. and not compatible with d newer ones...